# On Defining Personalized Commands

Tags: math-mode, math-operators

Many times it takes a long time to write a mathematical formula using big commands. So I want to define a set of personalized commands that I frequently use. Please guide me.

Comment: Give us an example of a command you would like to define? You would like a command to do what? For example, print, calculate, etc..?

Comment: if by "big commands" you mean commands with long names like `\longrightarrow` then many Tex editors will allow you to enter them with a few keystrokes so defining shorter names doesn't help much and makes it harder for anyone reading your file to understand as they will not immediately recognise the command names.

Comment: @David Carlisle +1 for one guessing of "big commands"

Answer (score 1):

Generally, your personal commands of the type you ask will fall into one of two categories: they will either take an argument or they will be fixed (not take an argument).  The fixed kind is merely some sort of shorthand to save yourself some typing.  They would be defined of the form:

```
\newcommand\mycommand{<fixed sequence of typeset math>}
```

The kind that take arguments, while they also perhaps save yourself some typing, define some kind of structure in which the argument is used to enunciate some variable in the defined structure.

The MWE below shows both cases:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\newcommand\Abarij{\bar A_{ij}}
\[\Abarij=0\]

\newcommand\Abarix[1]{\bar A_{i#1}}
\begin{align*}
\Abarix{k} &= \Abarij\\
\Abarix{l} &= 1\\
\Abarix{m} &= 2
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

[image]